# Error from custom function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

```
Function IFBLANK(param1 As Variant, param2 As Variant) As Variant
    If param1 = "" Or param1 Is Null Then
        IFBLANK = param2   
    Else
        IFBLANK = param1   
    End If 
End Function
```

I'm getting #VALUE error. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) This is not “*Jeopardy!* ”   We expect questions to be written in the form of a question.  (You know, with a question mark.  Imagine that you’re talking to a human being.)  (2) This is not Twitter; you are allowed — in fact, *encouraged* — to use more than 140 characters.

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

```
IsNull(param1) = True
```

instead of

```
param1 Is Null
```

Comment: (1) You almost never need to say `= True`.  You can say ``If param1 = "" Or IsNull(param1) Then``.  (2) We don’t like code-only answers.  (You are allowed — in fact, *encouraged* — to use more than 140 characters.)  Can you *explain* why `param1 Is Null` doesn’t work and `IsNull(param1)` does?

Comment: Actually, I don't know why. I accidentally make it works by trying code with similar concept.